# Why is the "new" Keyword necessary in C#

Tags: c#, keyword

Suppose I have a function foo that takes a vector class as input:

```
void Foo( Vector3 vector );
```

If I want to call this function:

```
Foo( new Vector3(1, 2, 3) );
```

Why is the new keyword necessary (in C#) at all?

In other languages eg: C++ there is no need to use new *in this case*. It just seems redundant

edit 1:
@ spender the following is perfectly valid C++

```
Foo ( Vector3(1, 2, 3) );
```

A Vector3 object will be created on the stack, no new/calloc/malloc required.

Comment: Because classes are not functions.

Comment: `In C++ there is no need to use new`. Sorry, what?

Comment: Your assumptions are flawed. You need to understand what `new` means, and the difference between instantiating a class and a method that returns an object.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Eh, there isn't, really. You construct a temporary object using `T(args)` syntax in C++. `new` is used for heap construction and you almost never use it directly.

Comment: @ Frederick If this example were written in C++ new would not need to be used.

Comment: @aCuria:...so how would the memory for your object be allocated without the `new` keyword? Minus points for `malloc`.

Comment: This question is not "primarily opinion-based". There may be a technical reason for `new` to be required (and even if there isn't, this is still a valid question).

Comment: @spender Clearly you'd use `calloc`.  Duh.

Comment: @spender: However the compiler decided to do it. `Foo(Vector3(1,2,3));` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @rightfold The OP doesn't appear to be concerned with the technicalities of it, their opinion is implied that requiring it is redundant so why was the choice made to have such requirement is the essence of the question.

Comment: All classes in C++ are value types.  The *class* keyword is a synonym for the *struct* keyword.  This makes it easy to create an instance of a C++ class on the stack.  But doesn't make it so easy to avoid creating accidental copies that kill perf or corrupting memory by forgetting to write a copy constructor and assignment operator.  Clearly comparing C++ with managed code is still a taboo subject at SO :(

Comment: Its difficult to clear-up the poster's confusion when you block me from answering right before I press the Post Answer button.

Comment: This is actually a damn good question. I’m not sure it’s on-topic here, since an answer is almost certainly speculative, but technically this is an interesting question and I’d wager that the downvoters just don’t get it. Exhibit A: @FrédéricHamidi’s comment, currently at 14 upvotes. Sigh.

Comment: @aCuria In C++ you're doing something very different when you include vs exclude the `new` keyword.  spender was trying to help you figure that out by asking you leading questions, rather than stating it.  The `new` keyword is needed in the language if you want the program to act the way it does when `new` is added.  If you don't *want* the behavior used by omiting the `new` then you need to use `new`.

Comment: @spender Implicitly. There is no technical restriction for this to require special syntax.

Comment: @spender Stack allocation of objects in C++ doesn't require new.  `Foo ( Vector3(1, 2, 3) );` will call the Vector3 constructor, and is not (necessarily) a method call.

Comment: @ spender I added an edit in my question to resolve yours and Fredericks confusion. I am familiar to C++ and very new to C#

Comment: @aCuria Your edit actually *doesn't* resolve spender's question.  In fact, it just demonstrates that you didn't understand it.

Comment: @Konrad, to be fair, when I posted that comment the question was saying `there is no need to use new`, period. The `in this case` elaboration was added later. For what it's worth, I also did not downvote, nor voted to close, nor voted to delete.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi A struct (value type) does not "require the `new` keyword" (in C#).

Comment: @Grant, ah, you're right, I stand corrected.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi When C++ gets make_unique I would argue there would be no need to use new 99% of the time. The 1% being custom memory managers ect.

Answer (score 12):

The keyword was deemed appropriate by the language designers.  It's common in C# that the language forces you to be aware of what is occurring, and either provides errors or warnings in many scenarios where it could have implicitly added features or "filled in" data for you.

C# always requires you to initialize your variables prior to usage.  In this case, forcing the `new` keyword makes it obvious (to the developer) that a new instance (if Vector3 is a class) or a fully constructed type (if Vector3 is a value type) will be passed in to your method, as opposed to the result of a method call.

> C++ there is no need to use new

Note that in C++ `new` is not optional here, at least without changing your function definition.  Using `new` would mean `Foo()` would require a different syntax.

A call without new (`Foo(Vector3(1,2,3));`) suggests that `Foo` is defined as `void Foo(Vector3 vector)`.  If you were to use `new Vector3`, then Foo would be defined `void Foo(Vector3* vector)`, as new will return a pointer to the type.

This is because C++ allows multiple forms of object allocation - you can stack allocate (without new) or allocate on the heap (using new).  C# does not have this difference - all reference types are always allocated in long term storage, and value types are allocated in a location depending on their context and usage.  The developer does not have the same level of control in C# as in C++ in terms of object usage and allocation.

At the end of the day, every language (with a concept of objects) has their own syntax and rules for object initialization and usage.  Each language is unique, which is partly why there are so many different languages.  In general, most languages are designed around a set of governing philosophies and apporaches, and the requirement to use `new` fits with C#'s approach of being very explicit when there is a chance for ambiguity (ie: is this a type constructor or a method?).

Comment: Your examples of Foo's signature are fail. A T& won't bind to a temporary, and anyone passing a raw pointer to a `new`'d object deserves to be shot except under some very special circumstances. Secondly, you don't explain *why* a constructor should be treated differently to a method.

Comment: So first you are saying that C# makes you aware of what’s occurring, and that `new` makes it obvious that a new instance is created. And then you highlight that C# fails to distinguish between the (quite fundamentally different) stack and heap allocation. I’m not convinced (and it’s also not true, C# doesn’t always require when creating a value type object, which *can* be created via copying when returned from a function).

Comment: @DeadMG Reed's examples are actually correct.  The OP stated, in the question, that in C++ the use of `new` is optional.  It could be added or removed freely.  That is incorrect.  You are doing something completely different in the two cases; so different that you would even need to change the signature of `Foo` when you added or removed `new`.  You are correct that it would be poor practice to new an object and then pass it right into `Foo` (because you couldn't free it).  That's not the point though; the point is that the change needs to be made just to get it to *compile*.

Comment: @Servy: He edited the T& one out (the `new` is still fail). But my primary gripe with this answer is he says "`new` is needed to be explicit" but doesn't say why explicitness is preferable over uniformity in this case.

Comment: @ Servy that is not what I meant ("Can be added or removed freely"). In C++ new cannot be used in this way.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm not saying its preferable - I'm saying it's *different*, and it fits with C#.  I completely agree that passing a new object into a function would be horrifically nasty code, but it will compile...

Comment: @aCuria In C++ you can create an object with or without using `new`.  They do radically different things in either case.  One allocates the space on the heap and gives you a pointer to that object, the other creates the value on the heap and doesn't provide a pointer to it.  If the semantics of your program require a heap allocation then you need to use `new` (or `malloc`/`calloc`) and if it doesn't, then you don't need `new`.

Comment: @Reed coming from C++ it is quite hard to see the ambiguity - It has always been clear to me when I am constructing an object vs calling a function. If you take this line of argument, do you also argue that C++ is ambiguous with regard to calling of a constructor vs method?

Comment: I am upvoting this answer, but my only problem with it is that C# is not always explicit. One glaring example is the var keyword, as well as a lot of different anonymous initialization and lambda syntax, C# syntax can often not be very clear or explicit.

Comment: @mao47 I specifically said C# is "explicit when there is a chance for ambiguity" - var, anonymous initialization, lambda syntax, etc - will always force you to be explicit if the compiler detects that there is more than one way to resolve the types.  Inferred typing is still very explicit.

Comment: @Reed Isn't the only time the new could be ambiguous when there is a method that shares the name of a class? Could there be another case where not having new is ambiguous? If this is the only one I can definitely see the argument for getting rid of "new".

Comment: @mao47 Yes, and the language could have rules for how to choose between them - but it wasn't done that way (for whatever reason, good or bad - the designers choose to make constructor calls explicit, and always different than method calls from a syntax standpoint).